# Query large JSON object for condition

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse [a large JSON object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/TOC.json) for a specific condition

My current approach is to set up a recursive filter:

```
function filter(obj,fn,items){
  //Initialise items array
  if(items==undefined)
    items = []

  //Filter for specific child objects
  if(obj.children!=undefined){
    obj.children.forEach(function(element){
      if(fn(element)){
        items.push(element)
      }
      filter(element,fn,items)
    })
  }

  //Return items
  return items
}
```

Called like:

```
filter(data.items[0],function(el){
  if(el.children != undefined)
    return el.children.filter(function(el){
      return el.toc_title == "Events"
    }).length>0
})
```

Which works well, but it seems to me that this kind of query would be fairly common... Is there an existing built-in function for doing this job?

Comment: [I also implemented an OOP approach for this with recursive structure compatibility](https://gist.github.com/sancarn/68003988e83581f09dbbaa85be6611bd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work in a correct way, although, you could use a combination between the method *map* and *filter* recursively. In this way, you will get a code more efficient.
[Here](http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2015/recursive-map-reduce-and-filter-in-javascript/) you can find some examples about how to use these functions recursively. An example could be:

```
let filteredFnc = (jsonObj) => jsonObj.filter(jsonObj => jsonObj.children !== undefined)
let map = (filteredFnc, obj) => !obj.length ? [] : [filteredFnc(obj[0])].concat(map(filtered, obj), obj.slice(1)));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Jeroen Heier!

Comment: That is crazy compact O_o Almost to the point it's confusing... xD